# Upload Image from the gallery into Firebase with Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase

I've got a problem regarding Firebase and the upload of pictures..

I've been tried to follow the Firebase doc but I'm not sur to do the right things ...

In my application I want to send in firebase the value of 2 textfields and 1 segmented control plus one picture which is coming from the iphone's gallery.

well my save button :

```
@IBAction func saveBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //Informations from the segmented control
    if isMe == false {// Si SE
        acftType = "SE"
    }else if isMe == true {//Si ME
        acftType = "ME"
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let usersPlanes : NSDictionary = [ "Registration" : self.acftRegTxtField.text!,
                                       "model": self.acftModelTxtField.text!,
                                       "Type" : self.acftType]

    if isMe == false {// Si SE
        ref.child("Planes").child(userID!).child("SE").childByAutoId().setValue(usersPlanes)
    }else if isMe == true {//Si ME
         ref.child("Planes").child(userID!).child("ME").childByAutoId().setValue(usersPlanes)
    }else{

        print("Error: Impossible to find the type of aircraft...")
    }



    let Dpalert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Your informations as been upload", preferredStyle: .alert)

    Dpalert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Roger", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(Dpalert, animated: true)
}
```

And my function to allow user to select an image from his gallery is :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.planImageView.image = selectedImage
        var data = Data()
        data = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)!

    }else{
        print("Error : Impossible to deal with this image...")
    }
    let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child(userID!).child(randomString(20));

    let uploadPict = imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil){ (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            return
        }

        let size = metadata.size

        imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {

                return
            }
        }
    }
```

But nothing appears in firebase when the picture is load in the app and How can I add it in the same folder as my first 3 information send with the save button ?

I'm totally lost with all this information. How can I solve my problem ?

Thanks very much for your help !

Flyer-74

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
    self.planImageView.image = selectedImage
    var data = Data()
    data = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)!

}else{
    print("Error : Impossible to deal with this image...")
}
let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child(userID!).child(randomString(20));

let uploadPict = imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil){ (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        return
    }

    let size = metadata.size

    imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        guard let downloadURL = url else {

            return
        }
    }
}
```

Try to put an output when your putData fail

```
    let uploadPict = imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil){ (metadata, error) in
    guard let metadata = metadata else {
        print("Error with upload \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        return
    }

    let size = metadata.size

    imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        guard let downloadURL = url else {
            print("Error with download URL: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will help you to recognize the error; tell me what you got in the error